# Scrapy - write to disk during crawl

Tags: python, scrapy

It looks like scrapy pipeline waits for the crawl to finish before writing to file. The persistence option (using JOBDIR) doesnt seem to write to output file during the crawl.

What are my options if I want to:

- a) Save every item as it appears
- b) Save every 10 items collected

Answer (score 1):

If you have issues with logging with scrapy,you can adjust your level of logging by adding a line to the settings.py file in your Scrapy project:

```
LOG_LEVEL = 'ERROR'
```

If you want to print output to separate file,you can do that this way from command line

```
scrapy crawl yourobject -s LOG_FILE= mynew.log
```

This is how I work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry , by output i mean the crawled items for example content from wikipedia. Rather than write to csv as each item is crawled and parsed, my crawler waits till its done before saving items to file. Your suggestion on the log file is helpful- i didnt think,to,sace it to file, but its a nice idea.